# Checking roles for an item

Tags: workflow, roles

How can I check if current user has roles for editing, creating an item in a list in Sequential Workflow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if current user has permissions on item, folder, list or site use [DoesUserHavePermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.doesuserhavepermissions%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything in SDP workflows that allows for that.  You'd have to make sure that the lists are permissioned appropriately or that those steps are being run under an impersenation step.